# XPath selector giving me two duplicate results for each article

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

I’m trying to grab the url of the cover image for each article (10 articles on the first page) on this website: [www.coindesk.com/tag/bitcoin/1/](http://www.coindesk.com/tag/bitcoin/1/)

but the following XPath

```
'//div[@class="img-block"]//img/@src'
```

gives me 20 results of 2 of the same url when I only want 10 of them. How can I take care of this problem so I don’t get duplicates?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Which language/tools/libs ?

Answer (score 1):

In a shell (if you are stuck with `XPath1`):

```
$ xidel -se '//div[@class="img-block"]//img/@src' \
   https://www.coindesk.com/tag/bitcoin/1/ |
    sort -u
```

If you use another language, the idea is to create an array and filter duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

With XPath 2.0:

```bash
distinct-values(//div[@class="img-block"]//img/@src)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because each article has 2 `//div[@class="img-block"]`-nodes. Please look at the parent- or ancestor-node for a unique identifier. The following 4 queries should all return the same output:

```
//div[starts-with(@class,"display-desktop-block")]/div/div/a/picture/img/@src
//div[starts-with(@class,"display-desktop-block")]//@src

//div[@class="under-headline-img"]/div/a/picture/img/@src
//div[@class="under-headline-img"]//@src
```

These return the urls to the lowest resolution image variant. If you want the highest resolution and best quality instead (with [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel)):

```
$ xidel -s "http://www.coindesk.com/tag/bitcoin/1" -e '
  //div[starts-with(@class,"display-desktop-block")]/div/div/a/picture/(source[@type="image/webp"])[last()]/tokenize(tokenize(@srcSet,", ")[2])[1]
'
$ xidel -s "http://www.coindesk.com/tag/bitcoin/1" -e '
  //div[@class="under-headline-img"]/div/a/picture/(source[@type="image/webp"])[last()]/tokenize(tokenize(@srcSet,", ")[2])[1]
'
```